# How to root my phone without PC?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have a indian phone . I am giving below its specifications

1. Manufature-Vox
2. Model-Kick k5
3. 1.2 Ghz single core processor
   4.512 MB RAM
4. 256 MB ROM
5. Android 4.4.2

I have tried many apps like framaroot, Vroot, Oneclick root, Universal Androot but theydonot work. Help me to root it without PC.

Comment: I am not sure but try using **Lambda ** app from [link](http://towelroot.com)

Answer (score 0):

I already rooted two devices with [towelroot](https://towelroot.com/) and it worked very well. But I'm not sure if it will work with your device.